# a query by linq number of join is dynamic

Tags: sql, linq, dynamic

I use Entity framework to connect to database. I have 3 tables in my database like

```
student(student_Id,name)
Course(course_Id,Name)
student_Course(student_Id,course_Id)
```

in my application number of course is constant but admin Determine number of course

now I want a Linq query (one query) to get result like this

```
student_name course_name1 course_name2 course_name3...(to count determined)
```

Comment: I don't understand the sentence _in my application number of course is constant but admin Determine number of course_

Comment: user can change number of course